# JSF PrimeFaces - store uploaded file path in another bean's attribute

Tags: spring, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, path

**To sum things up**: I want to upload file passed by user through a form with `<p:fileUpload>` using `fileUploadController` ManagedBean as its `fileUploadListener` to a certain path, then get this path along with filename and Store it somehow (the question is - how?) in the `wydarzenieMB` ManagedBean because I need `filePath` as a String in my `addWydarzenie()` method to store this path in a database and later use it.

I've got a table in my database named "Wydarzenie". It has many values like name etc. which I am specyfing in my JSF form for user to fill using primefaces. There is no problem with obtaining them, I just use ManagedBean to store input and later use this input to write into DataBase using addWydarzenie() method.

Part of utworzWydarzenie.xhtml form:

```
...
<h:outputLabel for="opis" value="Opis :" />
<p:inputTextarea id="opis" value="#{wydarzenieMB.opis}" label="opis">
...
<p:commandButton id="addWydarzenie" value="Zatwierdź" action="#{wydarzenieMB.addWydarzenie}" ajax="false"/>
```

My addWydarzenie() method in wydarzenieManagedBean:

```
public String addWydarzenie() {
    try {
        Wydarzenie wydarzenie = new Wydarzenie();
        ...
        wydarzenie.setOpis(getOpis());
        ...
        getWydarzenieServiceImpl().addWydarzenie(wydarzenie);
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return ERROR;
}
```

There is no problem with values like that where I use `p:inputText` for example, because I specify value of bean (for example: `value="#{wydarzenieMB.opis}"`) in which I want to store them. Problem begins with my `<p:fileUpload>` field because:
 1. I am not specyfing value there because there is no value returned(?) - only file uploaded
 2. I am using `fileUploadController` ManagedBean to handle file uploading BUT I want the filePath String of uploaded file that it possess to be stored in my `wydarzenieMB` ManagedBean.

Here's my uploading file code from utworzWydarzenie.xhtml form:

```
...
<h:outputLabel for="plakat" value="Plakat :" />
<p:fileUpload id="plakat" update="messages" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}" multiple="false" sizeLimit="1000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
...
```

And my fileUploadController class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="fileUploadController")
@RequestScoped
public class FileUploadController 
{  
private String destination="E:/PROJEKT ZESPOLOWY/events/WebContent/resources/plakaty/";
private String sciezkaPliku = "";           // complete file path including destination and file name

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException { 
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Plik: ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " został poprawnie wysłany na serwer.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    String path = destination;

    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String name = fmt.format(new Date())
            + event.getFile().getFileName().substring(
                  event.getFile().getFileName().lastIndexOf('.'));
    File file = new File(path + name);

    sciezkaPliku += path + name;            // I set file path here

    InputStream is = event.getFile().getInputstream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0)
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    is.close();
    out.close();
}   

public String getSciezkaPliku() {
    return sciezkaPliku;
}

public void setSciezkaPliku(String sciezkaPliku) {
    this.sciezkaPliku = sciezkaPliku;
}
}
```

It is declared as a ManagedBean because I've tried to access its `sciezkaPliku` variable which is filepath from `wydarzenieMB` like this:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{fileUploadController.sciezkaPliku}")
private String plakat;
```

But it was always null. I also tried to get whole `wydarzenieMB` inside `fileUploadController` and use it's setter method:

```
@ManagedBean(name="fileUploadController")
@RequestScoped
public class FileUploadController 
{  
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{wydarzenieMB}")
    WydarzenieManagedBean w;

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException { 

        ...
        sciezkaPliku += path + name;            // I set file path here
        w.setPlakat(sciezkaPliku);
        ...

    }
    ...
}
```

But it was unsuccessful either. File is uploaded and saved in a specified folder without a problem, when I print `sciezkaPliku` from `handleFileUpload` it is ok, but when I am creating my new Wydarzenie using `addWydarzenie()` it is always `null`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question clearly, I suggest you to change your scope to **"@SessionScoped"** in **FileUploadController**. I had a same problem and it was solved by this way.

check it out and inform me of the result ;)

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you very much! Never would have thought of that.